# Delete up everything until searched term, including searched term

Tags: search, cut-copy-paste

If the cursor is at `t` in

```
the quick brown fox
```

and we type `d/brown`, we delete `the quick` . Is there a way to extend this such that the searched term is deleted too? (Such that only  `fox` remains.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searches are exclusive by default. That means that you only delete up to the start of the *matched* text which is where the cursor would end up. We need some way to force the match/cursor to fall at a point that encompasses the whole pattern string. One way is to add the offset flag `/e`:

```
d/brown/e
```

With no numerical value specified after `/e` the offset is effectively 0 (from the flag's position) and the cursor falls on the last character of `brown`. Thus everything up to and including that character gets deleted. (Whereas, for example, `/e+2` (or more) would put the cursor past the pattern.)

Take a look at [`:h search-offset`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#search-offset) for details about `/e` and several other flags with related functions.

Alternatively, you can use the more familiar `\zs` to do accomplish the same thing:

```
d/brown\zs
```

This pattern atom "sets the start of the match" to its location. Since everything up to the start of the match is deleted this also has the the result we want.

See [`:h /\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#/%5Czs) for details.

Comment: `:help search-offset` lists a myriad of useful options

Comment: Yeah...still writing...usually put help links last. :)

Comment: Thank you both very much for the answers!

Comment: Yeah, I just verified that the above is correct. What implementation are you using that's doing it wrong. That's very strange!

Comment: Oh, yeah. No suprise there. That's a Vim emulator (no actual Vim code in it) and that's a well known bug (some claim it's a feature). Been like that for years. I'm somewhere in the comments under the bug report complaining about it. :)